# How to list all projects inside GCP organization using Custom Role

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to **list** all my **GCP projects** under the **organization** using **IAM Custom Role** and assign it to my new **Service Account**.

Could you let me know what exactly permissions should I add to this role for fine-grained access?

I also don't want to use these default permissions:

- roles/viewer
- roles/editor
- roles/owner

Comment: What about giving the `resourcemanager.projects.list` and `resourcemanager.projects.get` permissions ?
[Check this insight](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-proj#creating-custom-roles)

Comment: Unfortunately it's the first think I tried and it didn't work. With Owner permission it worked but this is not good for me.

Comment: You also need the `folder.list` and `folder.get` along with the two previous I mentionned.
You might want to try the Role: `roles/browser` also

Comment: Still not working. I assigned 4 permissions: resourcemanager.folders.get / resourcemanager.folders.list / resourcemanager.projects.get / resourcemanager.projects.list to my Alpha role and the output of the gcloud projects list command is 0

Comment: The roles/browser permission is the same (Listed 0 items)

Comment: It worked!

Using resourcemanager.folders.get / resourcemanager.folders.list / resourcemanager.projects.get / resourcemanager.projects.list

It probably took some time for it to modify  the new settings.

Comment: @vdolez could you please post an answer with the solution given in the comments?

Comment: @James yeah, access rights take about 5-10minutes to be propagated I guess.

Comment: @GabrielRobledoAhumada did it

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google's documentation about access control for projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-proj#creating-custom-roles) :

> When creating a Custom Role for use with Resource Manager, be aware of the following points:
>
> - List and get permissions, such as resourcemanager.projects.get/list, should always be granted as a pair.
> - When your Custom Role includes the folders.list and folders.get permissions, it should also include projects.list and projects.get.

So in order to be able to list every projects of an organisation, you'll need to provide the following permissions to your Custom Role:

- resourcemanager.projects.get
- resourcemanager.projects.list
- resourcemanager.folders.get
- resourcemanager.folders.list

Also, please note that the predefined role `roles/browser` regroup most of this scope without being overly permissive.

Granting new rights to a user or a Service Account is not necessarily immediate and may take up to 5/10min in order to be propagated.